# Arduino IDE 1.8.10 serial monitor has no speed setting

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

With Arduino IDE 1.8.10, there is no baud rate setting displayed at the bottom of the serial monitor.  I'm pretty sure this is essential.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The current release is 1.8.12
In 1.8.10 the developers also changed a lot in the build system. It was a disaster, so they reverted back to the old proven framework in 1.8.11 and relased a quite stable 1.8.12 soon afterwards. So [upgrade](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software)